# How to increase the margin of a plot to avoid legend cutoff when using ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)
library("ggpubr")
d1 <- data.frame(label = c("lots","of","categories", "in", "my","plot; some of them have really long names maybe. I am just trying to make this run off the page"),
                                value = c(100,200,300,400,5000,50000))
d1$group <- c(rep("", 6))

d2 <- data.frame(label = c("so","many","categories", "what", "to","do; some of them have really long names maybe. I am just trying to make this run off the page"),
                 value = c(100,200,300,400,5000,50000))
d2$group <- c(rep("", 6))

p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(fill=label, y=value, x=group)) + geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
p2 <- ggplot(d2, aes(fill=label, y=value, x=group)) + geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
panel_fig <- ggarrange(p1,
                       p2,
                       ncol=2,
                       legend="bottom",labels = c("A.", "B."))
ggsave("panel_fig.png", panel_fig)
```

I want to be able to show the entire legend without being cutoff. I have tried adjusting margins in `p1` and `p2` with different values in `theme(plot.margin = margin(100, 100, 100, 100))`, but no luck. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the margins, but some other things you can try:

- Enlarging the entire plot

```
ggsave("panel_fig.png", panel_fig, width = 10, height = 10, units = "in")
```

- Increasing the number of rows

```
p1 + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

- Forcing long names to span multiple lines

```
"do; some of them have really long names maybe.\nI am just trying to make this run off the page"
```